# Trying to workaround MS Edge lack of support for clip-path

Tags: html, css, svg, background-image

Context: Edge only supports clip-path on `<svg>` elements.

This is what I've been trying. I have this `<image>` in an `<svg>`, and I'm trying to style it as if it were a background-image. You know, *background-attachment fixed*, *background-size cover* and all that. Problem is... how?

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="highlight-clip-row">
      <polygon points="30 0, 100 0, 100 100, 0 100"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="highlight-clip-column">
      <polygon points="0 25, 100 0, 100 100, 0 100"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image id="highlight-image" xlink:href="{{ asset('images/highlight.jpg') }}" height="100%" width="100%"/>
</svg>
```

The following is the expected result (on Firefox) without using `<svg>`, which does not work on MS Edge:

[image: Example of expected result]

For a live example of this, go to [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/). `clip-path` will not work on MS Edge because it's using a simple div with a background image.

This image is supposed to behave as a background image for a div, which is a flex item in a responsive flex container.

I've tried to omit the `xlink:href` attribute and simply add a background-image to its  element, but nothing is displayed on it.

If I save this `<svg>` element as a file and reference it as a background image for a div, how would I use the two of those `clipPath` elements?

If there's another way to achieve the same effect, I would be glad to hear. I've been searching all day.

Comment: Remove width and height of the svg element. Then use this tool [SVG-encoder](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs) and use the encoded result as background image.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this solution with svg as a fallback for edge
This will work in IE9 and later, as well as Firefox and Chrome

```
<svg class="svg-graphic" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<g>
   <clipPath id="hexagonal-mask">
      <polygon points="30,0 100,0 100,100 0,100" />
   </clipPath>
</g> 
<image clip-path="url(#hexagonal-mask)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beautiful-beauty-blue-bright-414612.jpg&fm=jpg"/></svg>
```